# Find indices of duplicate rows in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the pandas way of finding the indices of identical rows within a given DataFrame without iterating over individual rows?

While it is possible to find all unique rows with `unique = df[df.duplicated()]` and then iterating over the unique entries with `unique.iterrows()` and extracting the indices of equal entries with help of `pd.where()`, what is the pandas way of doing it?

**Example:**
Given a DataFrame of the following structure:

```
  | param_a | param_b | param_c
1 | 0       | 0       | 0
2 | 0       | 2       | 1
3 | 2       | 1       | 1
4 | 0       | 2       | 1
5 | 2       | 1       | 1
6 | 0       | 0       | 0
```

Output:

```
[(1, 6), (2, 4), (3, 5)]
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use parameter [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with `keep=False` for all dupe rows and then `groupby` by all columns and convert index values to tuples, last convert output `Series` to `list`:

```
df = df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]

df = df.groupby(list(df)).apply(lambda x: tuple(x.index)).tolist()
print (df)
[(1, 6), (2, 4), (3, 5)]
```

If you want also see duplicate values:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(df.columns.tolist())
       .apply(lambda x: tuple(x.index))
       .reset_index(name='idx'))
print (df1)
   param_a  param_b  param_c     idx
0        0        0        0  (1, 6)
1        0        2        1  (2, 4)
2        2        1        1  (3, 5)
```

Comment: I tried your solution, and while it worked with the toy example, it threw the error *AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tolist'* when I tried to use it on my own data frame. Is there something in your solution that is specific to DFs which  only contain numbers (my DF entries are mostly strings)?

Comment: I get AttributeError when all rows are unique resulting in empty DataFrames, fixed using `df = df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['a','b','c'], keep=False),['a','b','c']]` in the first line

Answer (score 6):

**Approach #1**

Here's one vectorized approach inspired by [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44999009/)-

```
def group_duplicate_index(df):
    a = df.values
    sidx = np.lexsort(a.T)
    b = a[sidx]

    m = np.concatenate(([False], (b[1:] == b[:-1]).all(1), [False] ))
    idx = np.flatnonzero(m[1:] != m[:-1])
    I = df.index[sidx].tolist()       
    return [I[i:j] for i,j in zip(idx[::2],idx[1::2]+1)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [42]: df
Out[42]: 
   param_a  param_b  param_c
1        0        0        0
2        0        2        1
3        2        1        1
4        0        2        1
5        2        1        1
6        0        0        0

In [43]: group_duplicate_index(df)
Out[43]: [[1, 6], [3, 5], [2, 4]]
```

**Approach #2**

For integer numbered dataframes, we could reduce each row to a scalar each and that lets us work with a `1D` array, giving us a more performant one, like so -

```
def group_duplicate_index_v2(df):
    a = df.values
    s = (a.max()+1)**np.arange(df.shape[1])
    sidx = a.dot(s).argsort()
    b = a[sidx]

    m = np.concatenate(([False], (b[1:] == b[:-1]).all(1), [False] ))
    idx = np.flatnonzero(m[1:] != m[:-1])
    I = df.index[sidx].tolist() 
    return [I[i:j] for i,j in zip(idx[::2],idx[1::2]+1)]
```

---

**Runtime test**

Other approach(es) -

```
def groupby_app(df): # @jezrael's soln
    df = df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]
    df = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).apply(lambda x: tuple(x.index)).tolist()
    return df
```

Timings -

```
In [274]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(100000,3)))

In [275]: %timeit group_duplicate_index(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 36.1 ms per loop

In [276]: %timeit group_duplicate_index_v2(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 15 ms per loop

In [277]: %timeit groupby_app(df) # @jezrael's soln
10 loops, best of 3: 25.9 ms per loop
```