# Edit duplicates in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table containing node names, node x-coordinates and node y-coordinates.
Some of them containing identical x and y coordinates. 
I want to plot this table in a scatter-like method to visualize the node schemes. To do this, I don't want the nodes (with identical x&y) to overlay each other in the plot since this does not favour the scheme-like representation. So, I want to change the x-coordinates to be positioned next to each other.

Example:

```
a, 10, 30
b, 10, 30
c, 10, 30
d, 50, 80
e, 90, 60
f, 100, 20
g, 120, 40
h, 120, 40
i, 120, 40
```

Nodes a, b and c would overlay each other. Vary the x coordinates of those by (e.g.) 10%, see the attached image.

[Scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4uEi.png)

My first step was to round the results and get possible duplicates via:

```
pd.concat(g for _, g in df.groupby("x") if len(g) >1)
```

Now I am completely unsure how I shall go on. Can somebody help me here please?

Comment: can equal rows be not consecutive?

Comment: how do you want to vary the coordinates? b should be 10% larger than a and c should be 10% larger than b?

Comment: Hi Joe. Yes, the order of the origin/root dataframe can be random. Also the resulting dataframe can be random. Only the correct association of node name(a,b,c..) and coordinates has to be assured.

Hi @Yuca, in the best case, the method would count the numbers of overlaying nodes. If there are 5 nodes overlaying, the 3rd one is maintaining the coordinates. The first of them is assigned with -20% x, the second with -10%, fourth +10%, fifth +20% etc. The order of the five nodes does not matter (so far)

Comment: oh man, that's too much work, i'll give you a method to find the dups and you work your way up lol

Comment: this helps you to find the duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/a/46629549/9754169

Answer (score 1):

Try the following approach.

```
def adjust(x):
    # create a list of numbers to multiply (adjust)
    # the original data by
    if not len(x) % 2:
        r = range(-(len(x)//2), (len(x)//2))
    else:
        r = range(-(len(x)//2), (len(x)//2)+1)
    mult = list(map(lambda x: 1+x/10, r))
    return x*mult

# find all duplicates
dup = df.duplicated(subset='x', keep=False)
# update the values of duplicates using the above function
df.loc[dup, 'x'] = df[dup].groupby('x').x.apply(adjust)
```

> Example:

**Input Data**:

```
a, 10, 30
b, 10, 30
c, 10, 30
d, 50, 80
e, 90, 60
f, 100, 20
g, 120, 40
h, 120, 40
i, 120, 40
```

**Output DataFrame:**

```
   node x        y
0   a   9.0     30
1   b   10.0    30
2   c   11.0    30
3   d   50.0    80
4   e   90.0    60
5   f   100.0   20
6   g   96.0    40
7   h   108.0   40
8   i   120.0   40
9   j   132.0   40
10  k   144.0   40
```