# Find not duplicated indice of dataframe for same index by pandas?

Tags: pandas

Example:

```
 | param_a | param_b | param_c
1 | 0       | 0       | 0
1 | 0       | 2       | 1
3 | 2       | 1       | 1
4 | 0       | 2       | 1
3 | 2       | 1       | 1
4 | 0       | 0       | 0
4 | 0       | 0       | 0
```

For duplicated index(1,3,4), I want to find them where each indice is different. Take index 1 and 4 for example, there are different indices.

Output:

```
   param_a  param_b  param_c     
1        0        0        0  
1        0        2        1  
4        0        2        1
4        0        0        0
```

Notice: it returns unique indices for each duplicated index.

I refered [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46629549/5576930) but could not get the answer.

Comment: why `3 | 2 | 1 | 1` is removed? and `4 | 0 | 0 | 0` kept?

Comment: @QuangHoang I have updated my question, I want to find duplicated indexes where their indices are not totally the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert index to column and remove duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and then get all duplicates per column `index` by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `keep=False` and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df.reset_index().drop_duplicates()
print (df)
   index  param_a  param_b  param_c
0      1        0        0        0
1      1        0        2        1
2      3        2        1        1
3      4        0        2        1
6      4        0        0        0

print (df['index'].duplicated(keep=False))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
6     True
Name: index, dtype: bool
```

---

```
df1 = df[df['index'].duplicated(keep=False)].set_index('index').rename_axis(None)
print (df1)
   param_a  param_b  param_c
1        0        0        0
1        0        2        1
4        0        2        1
4        0        0        0
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, using `tuple` , after `reset_index` get all value in the df as group key , then we filter the df by `transform` `nunique` , and then `drop_duplicates`

```
s=df.reset_index()
yourdf=s[s.apply(tuple, 1).groupby(s['index']).transform('nunique') > 1].\
         drop_duplicates().\
            set_index('index')
yourdf
Out[207]: 
       param_a  param_b  param_c
index                           
1            0        0        0
1            0        2        1
4            0        2        1
4            0        0        0
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this way with [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html): (There is also parameter `keep` to keep the duplicates or no):

```
df=df.reset_index()
mask = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[list(df)], axis=1), index=df.index).duplicated()
df1 = df[~mask]
df1=df1.set_index('index')
```

---

```
   param_a  param_b  param_c
1        0        0        0
1        0        2        1
3        2        1        1
4        0        2        1
3        2        1        1
4        0        0        0
4        0        0        0
   index  param_a  param_b  param_c
0      1        0        0        0
1      1        0        2        1
2      3        2        1        1
3      4        0        2        1
4      3        2        1        1
5      4        0        0        0
6      4        0        0        0
       param_a  param_b  param_c
index                           
1            0        0        0
1            0        2        1
3            2        1        1
4            0        2        1
4            0        0        0
```

---

If you try to keep the duplicates:

```
mask = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[list(df)], axis=1), index=df.index).duplicated(keep=False)
```

You will end in result:

```
       param_a  param_b  param_c
index                           
1            0        0        0
1            0        2        1
4            0        2        1
```

Which is again close but it is not taking the duplicated row because there :

```
4            0        0        0
```

In account since it has a duplicate row (with that index 4) and it should because there is another row with starting index 4.

So this was close, but it is straight forward approach.

Comment: I know it is not the same output ;)

Comment: Will try to understand. Tnx.