# How do I classify simple data, after labeling

Tags: python, pandas

I am making a model to determine if people are duplicates.

People have attributes of name, age, gender, and weight.

I label people as duplicates if their name, and one of age, gender and weight are the same.

How do I make a model to classify people as the same? It seems like the features I used to label the data are the best classifiers, but if I don't use the features to label data, I can't label my very large(10k) dataset.

Comment: Are you using any machine learning algorithm here? If yes, you should mention which one and also add concerned tags to your question.

Comment: If this *I label people as duplicates if their name, and one of age, gender and weight are the same.* is your algorithm, you don't really need any model.

Comment: ok. I just want to validate my results, and make sure im doing things correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find indices of duplicate rows in pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46629518/find-indices-of-duplicate-rows-in-pandas-dataframe)