# Removing duplicates in dataframe via creating a list of their indices pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe (=`used_dataframe`), that contains duplicates. I am required to create a list that contains the indices of those duplicates
For this I used a function I found here:
[Find indices of duplicate rows in pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46629518/find-indices-of-duplicate-rows-in-pandas-dataframe/46629549)

```
def duplicates(x):

    #dataframe = pd.read_csv(x)
    #df = dataframe.iloc[: , 1:]
    df = x

    duplicateRowsDF = df[df.duplicated()]

    df = df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]
    tuppl = df.groupby(list(df)).apply(lambda x: tuple(x.index)).tolist() #this is the function!

    n = 1 # N. . .
    indicees = [x[n] for x in tuppl]
    
    return indicees

duplicates(used_df)
```

The next function I need is one, where I remove the duplicates from the dataset which i did like this:

```
    x= tidy(mn)

    indices = duplicates(tidy(mn))

    used_df = x
    used_df['indexcol'] = range(0, len(tidy(mn)))
    
    dropped = used_df[~used_df['indexcol'].isin(indices)]

    finito = dropped.drop(columns=['indexcol'])
    
    return finito

handling_duplicate_entries(used_df)
```

And it works - but when I want to check my solution  (to assess, that all duplicates have been removed)
Which I do by `duplicates(handling_duplicate_entries(used_df))`which should return an empty dataframe to show that there are no duplicates, it returns the error `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tolist'.`
In the question of the link above, this has also been added as a comment but not solved - and to be quite frank I would love to find a different solution for the duplicates function because I don't quite understand it but so far I haven't.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I'll try to do my best.

So if you are trying to find the duplicate indices, and want to store those values in a list you can use the following code. Also I have included a small example to create a dataframe containing the duplicated values (original), and the data without any duplicated data.

```
import pandas as pd

# Toy dataset
data = {
    'A': [0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0],
    'B': [0, 1, 3, 2, 3, 0],
    'C': [0, 1, 3, 2, 3, 0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
group = df.groupby(list(df.columns)).size()
group = group[group>1].reset_index(name = 'count')
group = group.drop(columns=['count']).reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'count'})
idxs = df.reset_index().merge(group, how = 'right')['index'].values
duplicates = df.loc[idxs]
no_duplicates = df.loc[~df.index.isin(idxs)]


duplicates
    A   B   C
0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0
2   3   3   3
4   3   3   3

no_duplicates
   A    B   C
1   0   1   1
3   0   2   2
```