# Create binary array of matching rows in an array using numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, vectorization

I'd like to create a binary array that shows all the matching rows in a numpy array. In this case, down column `j` of the new matrix, the ith index would correspond to `1` if row `i` from the original matrix was the same as row `j` from the original matrix.

For example, if the matrix looks like:

```
[ [a b c]
  [d e f]
  [a b c]
  [d e f]]
```

What I want to output is

```
[[1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1]]
```

Right now, I'm doing it via a loop like this:

```
same_mat=np.empty((agents,agents))
for i in range(matrix.shape[0]):
    same_mat[:,i]=np.all(matrix[i,:]==matrix,axis=1)
```

However, this is slow as it must go through each row in the original matrix individually to generate each column in the new matrix. Is there any vectorized way to do this faster?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** We can simply extend the array two 3D versions and compare and thus let [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) do its magic -

```
(arr[:,None] == arr).all(2).astype(int)
```

Sample run -

```
In [19]: a,b,c,d,e,f = 4,7,3,1,8,2
    ...: arr = np.array([
    ...:   [a, b, c],
    ...:   [d ,e, f],
    ...:   [a ,b, c],
    ...:   [d ,e, f]])
    ...: 

In [20]: arr
Out[20]: 
array([[4, 7, 3],
       [1, 8, 2],
       [4, 7, 3],
       [1, 8, 2]])

In [21]: (arr[:,None] == arr).all(2).astype(int)
Out[21]: 
array([[1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

**Approach #2 :** Memory efficient approach using `views`, as we reduce each row to one *value* each and then do `broadcasted-comparison`  -

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/44999009/ @Divakar
def view1D(a): # a is array
    a = np.ascontiguousarray(a)
    void_dt = np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1]))
    return a.view(void_dt).ravel()

arr1D = view1D(arr)
out = (arr1D[:,None] == arr1D).astype(int)
```

**Approach #3 :** For the love of built-ins, here's another that's similar in theory to the previous one, but using [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with its new `axis` functionality -

```
ids = np.unique(arr, axis=0, return_inverse=1)[1]
out = (ids[:,None] == ids).astype(int)
```

**Approach #4 :** Another way to tag each row based on their unique-ness among other rows would be to consider each row as linear index equivalents on a `2D` grid, giving us a more performant way to get `ids` -

```
ids = arr.dot((arr.max()-arr.min()+1)**np.arange(arr.shape[1]))
out = (ids[:,None] == ids).astype(int)
```

If we are guaranteed to have positive numbers, skip`arr.min()` there.

We need to be careful here though as with huge variation of numbers or with good number of columns would cause overflow. So, keep those in mind while using this approach.

**Extra stuffs**

To squeeze out maximum performance, use `uint8` as the output dtype, which seems fine given we only need to have `0s` and `1s` in the output, as shown in the timings below -

```
In [41]: bool_arr = np.random.rand(100,100)>0.5

In [42]: %timeit bool_arr.astype(int)
    ...: %timeit bool_arr.astype(np.uint8)
    ...: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.15 µs per loop
1000000 loops, best of 3: 897 ns per loop

In [43]: bool_arr = np.random.rand(5000,5000)>0.5

In [44]: %timeit bool_arr.astype(int)
    ...: %timeit bool_arr.astype(np.uint8)
    ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 21 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.16 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm going to test both out and time them and report back which is faster (also compared to looping) so other users with similar questions can have an idea of what they may want to use.

Comment: Interestingly, method 1 didn't save time compared to looping. However, my machine has no GPU and when actually run I will be using a machine with a GPU. Perhaps will test then and post time results.

Thank you so much for putting in all this effort!