# Finding duplicate rows in Pandas, where order of column values don't matter

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = data = { 'num1': [1,2,3,4,5], 
        'num2': [1,1,2,3,1],
        'num3': [5,4,3,2,1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df.head())




>>> df.head()
   num1  num2  num3          
0     1     1     5                   #dups with row 4
1     2     1     4
2     3     2     3
3     4     3     2
4     5     1     1                  #dups with row 1
```

In this sample dataframe, I'm trying to extract the first row and last row,
as their **contents** are duplicates of each other (1,1,5)

The code below will only find duplicated rows if order of values are the same (It seems):

```
dups =df[df.duplicated(subset=None, keep='first')]
```

thus is resulting in a empty dataset.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
In [257]: df[pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values), columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
               .duplicated(keep='first')]
Out[257]:
   num1  num2  num3
4     5     1     1
```

or if you need all duplicates:

```
In [258]: df[pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values), columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
               .duplicated(keep=False)]
Out[258]:
   num1  num2  num3
0     1     1     5
4     5     1     1
```

Comment: This seems to work as well. I will play around with your answer as well as the above answer and see which one seems best. Thank you.

Comment: @Moondra if you like their answer, you can upvote :-)

Answer (score 4):

**Approach #1 : `numpy.unique` based**

Here's one approach using recently added `axis` functionality with `np.unique` -

```
In [64]: s = np.sort(df.values, axis=1)

In [65]: unq, tag, count = np.unique(s, axis=0, return_counts=1, return_inverse=1)

In [66]: df[np.in1d(tag, np.flatnonzero(count > 1))]
Out[66]: 
   num1  num2  num3
0     1     1     5
4     5     1     1
```

Alternatively, the last step could be simplified -

```
In [63]: df[count[tag] > 1]
Out[63]: 
   num1  num2  num3
0     1     1     5
4     5     1     1
```

---

**Approach #2 : View and index-sorting based**

This one's focused on performance -

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/44999009/ @Divakar
def view1D(a): # a is array
    a = np.ascontiguousarray(a)
    void_dt = np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1]))
    return a.view(void_dt).ravel()

# Get duplicate rows indices off an array with order of elems being insensitive
def duprows_order_insensitive(ar): # ar is array
    s = np.sort(ar, axis=1)
    s_view1D = view1D(s)
    sidx = s_view1D.argsort()
    s_view1D_sorted = s_view1D[sidx]

    mask0 = s_view1D_sorted[1:] == s_view1D_sorted[:-1]
    mask = np.r_[False,mask0]
    mask[:-1] |= mask0
    return sidx[mask] # sort these if sorted indices are needed
```

Hence, the desired output would be obtained like so -

```
df.iloc[duprows_order_insensitive(df.values)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [234]: df
Out[234]: 
   num1  num2  num3
0     1     1     5
1     5     5     5
2     2     1     4
3     1     5     1
4     4     3     2
5     5     1     1
6     1     4     2

In [235]: df.iloc[duprows_order_insensitive(df.values)]
Out[235]: 
   num1  num2  num3
0     1     1     5
3     1     5     1
5     5     1     1
2     2     1     4
6     1     4     2
```

Comment: @Divakar  The df[count[tag] > 1] was really clever.