# Group duplicate column names in pandas DataFrame with missing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, nan

I am working with large *DataFrames* containing columns with unique IDs but duplicate values. These columns are dropped through `df.T.drop_duplicates().T`, but I need to know which ones were equivalent.

**Example:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],'B': [2, 4, 2, 1, 9], 'C': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],'D': [2, 4, 2, 1, 9], 'E': [3, 4, 2, 1, 2],'F': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],'G': [1, 1, 1, 1, np.nan],'H': [1, 1, 1, 1, np.nan], 'I': [1, 2, 3, np.nan, 5]}, dtype=np.float64)

print(df)
     A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I
0  1.0  2.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  2.0  4.0  2.0  4.0  4.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  2.0
2  3.0  2.0  3.0  2.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  3.0
3  4.0  1.0  4.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN
4  5.0  9.0  5.0  9.0  2.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  5.0
```

Several efficient solutions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44998223/group-duplicate-column-ids-in-pandas-dataframe) return nothing for columns containing `np.nan`:

**First Solution:**

```
def group_duplicate_rows(df):
    a = df.values
    sidx = np.lexsort(a.T)
    b = a[sidx]

    m = np.concatenate(([False], (b[1:] == b[:-1]).all(1), [False] ))
    idx = np.flatnonzero(m[1:] != m[:-1])
    C = df.index[sidx].tolist()
    return [C[i:j] for i,j in zip(idx[::2],idx[1::2]+1)]

In  [19]: group_duplicate_cols(df)
Out [19]: [['A', 'C'], ['B', 'D']]
```

**Second Solution:**

```
def view1D(a): # a is array
    a = np.ascontiguousarray(a)
    void_dt = np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1]))
    return a.view(void_dt).ravel()

def group_duplicate_cols_v2(df):
    a = df.values
    sidx = view1D(a.T).argsort()
    b = a[:,sidx]

    m = np.concatenate(([False], (b[:,1:] == b[:,:-1]).all(0), [False] ))
    idx = np.flatnonzero(m[1:] != m[:-1])
    C = df.columns[sidx].tolist()
    return [C[i:j] for i,j in zip(idx[::2],idx[1::2]+1)]

In  [20]: group_duplicate_cols_v2(df)
Out [20]: [['B', 'D'], ['A', 'C']]
```

Is there a way to adapt these functions to work with missing values?

Comment: You can first replace all the NaN with some value(let x) then apply group by. This will achieve the objective. But you have to think about the value "x" with which you can replace NaN, so that it will not affect the whole dataset meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `nan` elements with some value not present in your dataframe (e.g. `-1` if you only have positive numbers), using `pandas.fillna()`:

```
df.fillna(-1, inplace=True)
```

Will return:

```
    A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I
0  1.0  2.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  2.0  4.0  2.0  4.0  4.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  2.0
2  3.0  2.0  3.0  2.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  3.0
3  4.0  1.0  4.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0 -1.0
4  5.0  9.0  5.0  9.0  2.0  1.0 -1.0 -1.0  5.0
```

Comment: Thanks to both RobJan and michetonu for this straightforward solution. I simply called the function with group_duplicate_cols_v2(df.fillna(-999999.99)), which does not touch the original DataFrame but makes the function work.