# find duplicates and mark as variant

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, duplicates

I'm trying to create a data frame where I add duplicates as variants in a column.To further illustrate my question:

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
    Case    ButtonAsInteger
0   1       130
1   1       133
2   1       42
3   2       165
4   2       158
5   2       157
6   3       158
7   3       159
8   3       157
9   4       130
10  4       133
11  4       43
... ...     ...
```

I have converted it into this form:

```
grouped = activity2.groupby(['Case'])
values = grouped['ButtonAsInteger'].agg('sum')
id_df = grouped['ButtonAsInteger'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values)).unstack(level=-1


        0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9
Case                                                                                    
1       130.0   133.0   42.0    52.0    47.0    47.0    32.0    94.0    NaN     NaN
2       165.0   158.0   157.0   141.0   142.0   142.0   142.0   142.0   142.0   147.0
3       158.0   159.0   157.0   147.0   166.0   170.0   169.0   130.0   133.0   133.0
4       130.0   133.0   42.0    52.0    47.0    47.0    32.0    94.0    NaN     NaN
```

And now I want to find duplicates and mark each duplicate as a variant. So in this example, Case 1 and 4 should get variant 1. Like this:

```
        Variants    0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9
Case                                                                                        
1       1           130.0   133.0   42.0    52.0    47.0    47.0    32.0    94.0    NaN     NaN
2       2           165.0   158.0   157.0   141.0   142.0   142.0   142.0   142.0   142.0   147.0
3       3           158.0   159.0   157.0   147.0   166.0   170.0   169.0   130.0   133.0   133.0
4       1           130.0   133.0   42.0    52.0    47.0    47.0    32.0    94.0    NaN     NaN
```

I have already tried this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/44999009. But it doesn't work on my data frame. Unfortunately I don't know why.

It will probably be possible to apply a double for loop. So for each line look if there is a duplicate in the record. Whether this is efficient on a large record, I don't know.

I have also added my procedure with grouping, because perhaps there is a possibility to already work with duplicates at this point?

Comment: For those people who consider the question negative, could you please tell me why? This is the only way I can change anything.

Comment: I think your question is perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback,

Comment: Not my downvote. But it might help if you would explain in more detail what "the other post doesn't work" means more specifically. Does it not run or does it produce wrong results or ...?

Comment: @jotasi I'll take it into account next time. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This groups by all columns and returns the group index (+ 1 because zero based indexing is the default). I think this should be what you want.

```
id_df['Variant'] = id_df.groupby(
    id_df.columns.values.tolist()).grouper.group_info[0] + 1
```

The resulting data frame, given your input data like above:

```
        0    1    2  Variant
Case                        
1     130  133   42        1
2     165  158  157        3
3     158  159  157        2
4     130  133   42        1
```

There could be a syntactically nicer way to access the group index, but i didn't find one.

Comment: By the duplicate I get the variant value 1, by all others only the value 0. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @KoYan I can't really reproduce it with the data you have given above. On your example, everything works as you can see. Must be a problem that is not covered by your example

Comment: @KoYan Are your values integers like in the first dataframe or floats like in the second? It could be a floating point comparison problem. If your values are floats, you should cast them to integer before grouping.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works after cast to integer. Why does the apply function from above make floats? I can't understand that. Because the variable values still exists integers.

Comment: @KoYan I don't think the problem is with the code you posted. I ran your code to pivot the integer data you posted and i got integers. I can only assume that you already have float dtypes before you run that code. Glad it works for you now.

Comment: If you are interested, you can have a look at this cloud environment https://repl.it/repls/FairWelllitZettabyte After the apply function everything becomes float.

Comment: @KoYan That is some weird stuff. Possibly worthy of a separate SO question. ;-D All i can tell you is that your code works on my linux machine with python 3.6.