# Fast combination of non-unique rows in numpy array, mapped to columns (i.e. fast pivot table problem, without Pandas)

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I wonder if anyone can offer any ideas or advice on the following coding problem please, where I'm particularly interested in a fast Python implementation (i.e. avoiding Pandas).

I have a (dummy example) set of data like:

```
|   User   |   Day   |   Place   |   Foo   |   Bar   |
      1         10        5          True     False
      1         11        8          True     False
      1         11        9          True     False
      2         11        9          True     False
      2         12        1          False    True
      1         12        2          False    True
```

containing data for 2 users ("user1" and "user2") at a given day/place, where there's 2 boolean values of interest (called foo and bar here).

I'm only interested in situations where data is logged for BOTH users at the same day & place. With these relevant data rows, I then want to make new columns for the day/place entries that describe the user and foo/bar as bools.. e.g.

```
|   Day   |   Place   |   User 1 Foo   |   User 1 Bar   |   User 2 Foo   |   User 2 Bar   |
    11           9          True            False              True           False
```

Each column data is stored in numpy arrays. I appreciate this is an ideal problem for pandas, using the pivot table feature (e.g. Pandas solution is:

```
user = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1], dtype=int)
day = np.array([10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12], dtype=int)
place = np.array([5,8,9,9,1,2], dtype=int)
foo = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], dtype=bool)
bar = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], dtype=bool) 

df = pd.DataFrame({
'user': user,
'day': day,
'place': place,
'foo': foo,
'bar': bar,
})
df2 = df.set_index(['day','place']).pivot(columns='user')

df2.columns = ["User1_foo", "User2_foo", "User1_bar", "User2_bar"]
df2 = df2.reset_index()
df2.dropna(inplace=True)
```

but in my practical usage, I have millions of rows of data and profiling shows that the dataframe usage and pivot operation is a performance bottleneck.

Therefore, how can I achieve the same output, i.e. numpy arrays for day, place and user1_foo, user1_bar, user2_foo, user2_bar for just the cases where there is data for both users at the same day AND place in the original input arrays?

I wonder if somehow finding indexes from np.unique then inverting them would be a possible solution, but couldn't make it work. Therefore, any solutions (ideally fast executing) would be great thanks!

Comment: I can start writing this algorithm when I'm home from my concert, I know the mathematical formula for what you'd want and it may aid you on your quest to solve this optimization.

Comment: That would be amazing.. thanks. Would be great to see an algorithm or even just hear what this formula is. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again for your comments on this. If you get a chance, I wonder if you could let me know what this mathematical formula was you mentioned please - am very interested to look it up. Thanks!

Comment: I think your code is the most performative solution

Comment: In your actual use-case with millions of rows of data, do you have again exactly two users?

Comment: @Divakar: Yes, there will be only ever be two users.

Comment: @U10-Forward: thanks for the comment although I don't believe this is the case as Pandas usage does introduce an overhead and numerous examples are shown online how using numpy arrays can speed this up. I just haven't worked out the required numpy-based algorithm here.

Comment: Could there be duplicate rows .i.e. all entries including the user ID being identical?

Comment: No, this could not happen. Thanks for your many answers - this was useful and very instructive. Have selected it as the answer and will award the "bounty" when SO lets me in a few hours...

Comment: @SLater01 You still have 6 days for the end of bounty period. So, I suggest you delay the bounty transfer a bit longer. The question gets more attention. You might get better answers and also the proposed answers get attention.

Comment: Do you have any timing results from the various solutions?

Comment: I'll post answer on weekend :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Here's one based on dimensionality-reduction for memory-efficiency and [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) for tracing back and looking for matching ones between the two users data -

```
# Extract array data for efficiency, as we will work NumPy tools
a = df.to_numpy(copy=False) #Pandas >= 0.24, use df.values otherwise
i = a[:,:3].astype(int)
j = a[:,3:].astype(bool)
# Test out without astype(int),astype(bool) conversions and see how they perform

# Get grouped scalars for Day and place headers combined
# This assumes that Day and Place data are positive integers
g = i[:,2]*(i[:,1].max()+1) + i[:,1]

# Get groups for user1,2 for original and grouped-scalar items
m1 = i[:,0]==1
uj1,uj2 = j[m1],j[~m1]
ui1 = i[m1]
u1,u2 = g[m1],g[~m1]

# Use searchsorted to look for matching ones between user-1,2 grouped scalars
su1 = u1.argsort()
ssu1_idx = np.searchsorted(u1,u2,sorter=su1)
ssu1_idx[ssu1_idx==len(u1)] = 0
ssu1_idxc = su1[ssu1_idx]

match_mask = u1[ssu1_idxc]==u2
match_idx = ssu1_idxc[match_mask]

# Select matching items off original table
p1,p2 = uj1[match_idx],uj2[match_mask]

# Setup output arrays
day_place = ui1[match_idx,1:]
user1_bools = p1
user2_bools = p2
```

**Approach #1-Extended : Generic `Day` and `Place` dtype data**

We can extend to generic case when `Day` and `Place` data might not necessarily be positive integers. In that case, we can make use of dtype-combined view-based method to perform data-redcution. Thus, the only change needed would to get `g` differently and this would be a view-based array type and would be obtained like so -

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/44999009/ @Divakar
def view1D(a): # a is array
    a = np.ascontiguousarray(a)
    void_dt = np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1]))
    return a.view(void_dt).ravel()

# Get grouped scalars for Day and place headers combined with dtype combined view
g = view1D(i[:,1:])
```

**Approach #2**

We will use `lex-sorting` to group data in such a way that looking for identical elements in consecutive rows would tell us if there are matching ones across the two users. We will re-use `a,i,j` from `Approach#1`. The implementation would be -

```
# Lexsort the i table
sidx = np.lexsort(i.T)
# OR sidx = i.dot(np.r_[1,i[:,:-1].max(0)+1].cumprod()).argsort()

b = i[sidx]

# Get matching conditions on consecutive rows
m = (np.diff(b,axis=0)==[1,0,0]).all(1)
# Or m = (b[:-1,1] == b[1:,1]) & (b[:-1,2] == b[1:,2]) & (np.diff(b[:,0])==1)

# Trace back to original order by using sidx
match1_idx,match2_idx = sidx[:-1][m],sidx[1:][m]

# Index into relevant table and get desired array outputs
day_place,user1_bools,user2_bools = i[match1_idx,1:],j[match1_idx],j[match2_idx]
```

Alternatively, we could use an extended mask of `m` to index into `sidx` and generate `match1_idx,match2_idx`. Rest of the code stays the same. Hence, we could do -

```
from scipy.ndimage import binary_dilation

# Binary extend the mask to have the same length as the input.
# Index into sidx with it. Use one-off offset and stepsize of 2 to get
# user1,2 matching indices
m_ext = binary_dilation(np.r_[m,False],np.ones(2,dtype=bool),origin=-1)
match_idxs = sidx[m_ext]
match1_idx,match2_idx = match_idxs[::2],match_idxs[1::2]
```

**Approach #3**

Here's another based on `Approach #2` and ported over to `numba` for memory and hence perf. efficiency and we will re-use `a,i,j` from `approach #1` -

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def find_groups_numba(i_s,j_s,user_data,bools):
    n = len(i_s)
    found_iterID = 0
    for iterID in range(n-1):
        if i_s[iterID,1] == i_s[iterID+1,1] and i_s[iterID,2] == i_s[iterID+1,2]:
            bools[found_iterID,0] = j_s[iterID,0]
            bools[found_iterID,1] = j_s[iterID,1]
            bools[found_iterID,2] = j_s[iterID+1,0]
            bools[found_iterID,3] = j_s[iterID+1,1]
            user_data[found_iterID,0] = i_s[iterID,1]
            user_data[found_iterID,1] = i_s[iterID,2]        
            found_iterID += 1
    return found_iterID

# Lexsort the i table
sidx = np.lexsort(i.T)
# OR sidx = i.dot(np.r_[1,i[:,:-1].max(0)+1].cumprod()).argsort()

i_s = i[sidx]
j_s = j[sidx]

n = len(i_s)
user_data = np.empty((n//2,2),dtype=i.dtype)
bools = np.empty((n//2,4),dtype=j.dtype)    
found_iterID = find_groups_numba(i_s,j_s,user_data,bools)    
out_bools = bools[:found_iterID] # Output bool
out_userd = user_data[:found_iterID] # Output user-Day, Place data
```

Append with .copy() at last 2 steps if outputs must have their own memory spaces.

Alternatively, we can offload the indexing operation back on NumPy side for a cleaner solution -

```
@njit
def find_consec_matching_group_indices(i_s,idx):
    n = len(i_s)
    found_iterID = 0
    for iterID in range(n-1):
        if i_s[iterID,1] == i_s[iterID+1,1] and i_s[iterID,2] == i_s[iterID+1,2]:
            idx[found_iterID] = iterID
            found_iterID += 1            
    return found_iterID

# Lexsort the i table
sidx = np.lexsort(i.T)
# OR sidx = i.dot(np.r_[1,i[:,:-1].max(0)+1].cumprod()).argsort()

i_s = i[sidx]
j_s = j[sidx]

idx = np.empty(len(i_s)//2,dtype=np.uint64)
found_iterID = find_consec_matching_group_indices(i_s,idx)
fidx = idx[:found_iterID]
day_place,user1_bools,user2_bools = i_s[fidx,1:],j_s[fidx],j_s[fidx+1]
```

Answer (score 2):

**An alternative** - Find duplicate rows by *['day','place']* which will filter only the row which is common. Then make pivot by *'user'*. Change the column name and reindexing.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
user = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1], dtype=int)
day = np.array([10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12], dtype=int)
place = np.array([5,8,9,9,1,2], dtype=int)
foo = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], dtype=bool)
bar = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], dtype=bool)

df = pd.DataFrame({
'user': user,
'day': day,
'place': place,
'foo': foo,
'bar': bar,
})

df1=df[df.duplicated(['day','place'],keep=False)]\
    .set_index(['day','place']).pivot(columns='user')
name = df1.columns.names[1]
df1.columns = ['{}{}_{}'.format(name, col[1], col[0]) for col in df1.columns.values]
df1 = df1.reset_index()
```

**Output:**

```
   day  place  user1_foo  user2_foo  user1_bar  user2_bar
0   11      9       True       True      False      False
```

Comment: `df.duplicated(['day','place'],keep=False)]` was already included in my answer, you only added df.pivot which OP already used

Comment: Maybe, but when I have added that time I have not seen. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This  does use pandas, but it still might be helpful. Firast of all, perhaps first doing a search and removing, all rows that don't have duplicate day and place values could speed things up. For isntance, running `df2=df[df.duplicated(['day','place'],keep=False)]` will remove every row that has a unique day and place pair. I'm not sure what your data looks like, but this could significantly decrease the amount of data you have. For the example you gave, this line of code outputs

```
   user  day  place   foo    bar
2     1   11      9  True  False
3     2   11      9  True  False
```

After this pruning, it is possible to do simplified data extraction. Now, the code below only works if we know that there wont be any duplicate place and day entries for one user and if user one always comes first.

```
def every_other_row(df): 
    first=df.iloc[::2, :]
    second=df.iloc[1::2, :]
    first['foo user 2']=second['foo'].astype(bool)
    first['bar user 2']=second['bar'].astype(bool)

    return first
```

The conditions are very specific, but I included this option because when I ran this code on a DataFrame with a million rows took .289 s

Now, for a broader case, you could run something like this

```
df_user1=df.loc[df['user'] == 1] 
df_user2=df.loc[df['user'] == 2] 
df_user2=df_user2.rename(index=str, columns={"foo": "foo user 2", "bar": "bar user 2"})

new=df_user1.merge(df_user2,on=['day','place'])
```

Running this on 4.5 million rows took 3.8 seconds, though that will depend on how many rows are unique and need to be merged. I used random numbers to generate my DataFrame so maybe there was less data to combine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although there is still a large overhead from using pandas, even if reduced a little by dropping rows before performing operations. From reading online, using "apply" does seem to be slower for most operations than vectorised numpy array operations, hence my interest in a numpy solution

Comment: Well, pandas is based in numpy, so I don't know why it would necessarily be slower. The pivot operation is certainly slow but there might be something else out there. I'll investigate more and edit my answer if I can find something

Answer (score 1):

Here is a plain pythonic solution with `set` intersection:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

user = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1], dtype=int)
day = np.array([10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12], dtype=int)
place = np.array([5,8,9,9,1,2], dtype=int)
foo = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], dtype=bool)
bar = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], dtype=bool) 

# create a set of day/paces for user1
user1_dayplaces = { 
   (day[row_id], place[row_id])
   for row_id, user_id in enumerate(user)
   if user_id == 1
}

# create a set of day/paces for user2
user2_dayplaces = { 
   (day[row_id], place[row_id])
   for row_id, user_id in enumerate(user)
   if user_id == 2
}

# intersecting two sets to get the intended day/places
shared_dayplaces = user1_dayplaces & user2_dayplaces

# use day/places as a filter to get the intended row number
final_row_ids = [
   row_id
   for row_id, user_id in enumerate(user)
   if (day[row_id], place[row_id]) in shared_dayplaces
]

# filter the data with finalised row numbers to create the intended dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'user':  user[final_row_ids],
   'day':   day[final_row_ids],
   'place': place[final_row_ids],
   'foo':   foo[final_row_ids],
   'bar':   bar[final_row_ids],
}, final_row_ids) # setting the index in this like is only for keeping the original index numbers.
```

The resulted `df` is:

```
   user  day  place   foo    bar
2     1   11      9  True  False
3     2   11      9  True  False
```