# Find symmetric pairs quickly in numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(product(range(10), range(10)))
df = df.sample(90)
df.columns = "c1 c2".split()
df = df.sort_values(df.columns.tolist()).reset_index(drop=True)
#     c1  c2
# 0    0   0
# 1    0   1
# 2    0   2
# 3    0   3
# 4    0   4
# ..  ..  ..
# 85   9   4
# 86   9   5
# 87   9   7
# 88   9   8
# 89   9   9
# 
# [90 rows x 2 columns]
```

How do I quickly find, identify, and remove the last duplicate of all symmetric pairs in this data frame?

An example of symmetric pair is that '(0, 1)' is equal to '(1, 0)'. The latter should be removed.

The algorithm must be fast, so it is recommended to use numpy. Converting to python object is not allowed.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you understand by `symmetric pairs`?

Comment: (0, 1) == (1,0) is True

Comment: Is (0, 1) == (0, 1) also True?

Comment: @JerryM. Yes, but it is trivial to remove with `df.drop_duplicates()`

Comment: @molybdenum42 I use itertools product to create an example, the data themselves are not created with itertools product.

Comment: It is a general problem. The way I constructed the data is not relevant :)

Comment: Are those always integers in it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can sort the values, then `groupby`:

```
a= np.sort(df.to_numpy(), axis=1)
df.groupby([a[:,0], a[:,1]], as_index=False, sort=False).first()
```

**Option 2**: If you have a lot of pairs `c1, c2`, `groupby` can be slow. In that case, we can assign new values and filter by `drop_duplicates`:

```
a= np.sort(df.to_numpy(), axis=1) 

(df.assign(one=a[:,0], two=a[:,1])   # one and two can be changed
   .drop_duplicates(['one','two'])   # taken from above
   .reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
)
```

Answer (score 7):

One way is using [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with `return_index=True` and use the result to index the dataframe:

```
a = np.sort(df.values)
_, ix = np.unique(a, return_index=True, axis=0)

print(df.iloc[ix, :])

    c1  c2
0    0   0
1    0   1
20   2   0
3    0   3
40   4   0
50   5   0
6    0   6
70   7   0
8    0   8
9    0   9
11   1   1
21   2   1
13   1   3
41   4   1
51   5   1
16   1   6
71   7   1
...
```

Answer (score 6):

#### `frozenset`

```
mask = pd.Series(map(frozenset, zip(df.c1, df.c2))).duplicated()

df[~mask]
```

Comment: Aren't you iterating slowly over tuples over each column here? Still, upvote.

Comment: Yes, I'm iterating.  No, it isn't as slow as you think.

Answer (score 5):

I will do

```
df[~pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values,1)).duplicated().values]
```

From pandas and numpy tri

```
s=pd.crosstab(df.c1,df.c2)
s=s.mask(np.triu(np.ones(s.shape)).astype(np.bool) & s==0).stack().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's one NumPy based one for integers -

```
def remove_symm_pairs(df):
    a = df.to_numpy(copy=False)
    b = np.sort(a,axis=1)
    idx = np.ravel_multi_index(b.T,(b.max(0)+1))
    sidx = idx.argsort(kind='mergesort')
    p = idx[sidx]
    m = np.r_[True,p[:-1]!=p[1:]]
    a_out = a[np.sort(sidx[m])]
    df_out = pd.DataFrame(a_out)
    return df_out
```

If you want to keep the index data as it is, use `return df.iloc[np.sort(sidx[m])]`.

For generic numbers (ints/floats, etc.), we will use a `view-based` one -

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/44999009/ @Divakar
def view1D(a): # a is array
    a = np.ascontiguousarray(a)
    void_dt = np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1]))
    return a.view(void_dt).ravel()
```

and simply replace the step to get `idx` with `idx = view1D(b)` in `remove_symm_pairs`.

Answer (score 2):

If this needs to be *fast*, and if your variables are integer, then the following trick may help: let `v,w` be the columns of your vector; construct `[v+w, np.abs(v-w)] =: [x, y]`; then sort this matrix lexicographically, remove duplicates, and finally map it back to `[v, w] = [(x+y), (x-y)]/2`.