# Eliminate duplicate connections in undirected network

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an undirected network of connections in a dataframe.

```
    Source_ID    Target_ID
0       1            5
1       7            2     
2       12           6
3       3            9
4       16           11
5       2            7 <------The same as row 1
6       4            8
7       5            1 <------The same as row 0
8       99           81
```

But since this is an undirected network, row 0 and row 7 are technically the same, as are row 1 and row 5. `df.drop_duplicates()` isn't smart enough to know how to eliminate these as duplicates, as it see them as two distinct rows, at least as far as my attempts have yielded.

I also tried what I thought should work, which is using the index of `Source_ID` and `Target_ID` and setting `Source_ID` to be "lower" than `target_ID`. But that didn't seem to produce the results I needed either.

```
df.drop(df.loc[df['Target_ID'] < d['Source_ID']]
        .index.tolist(), inplace=True)
```

Therefore, I need to figure out a way to drop the duplicate connections (while keeping the first) such that my fixed dataframe looks like (after an index reset):

```
    Source_ID    Target_ID
0       1            5
1       7            2     
2       12           6
3       3            9
4       16           11
5       4            8
6       99           81
```

Comment: Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58592606/find-symmetric-pairs-quickly-in-numpy/58592764#58592764)

Comment: convert the dataframe to frozenset and then to dataframe. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not the most efficient, but might do the job:

```
df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series() if row[::-1].values in df.values \
         and row[0] < row[1] else row, axis=1).dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
```