# Removing symmetric pairs in DataFrame with MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pd.DataFrame` of the following form and numerical values in column 0 are not necessarily distinct:

```
>>> idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([["a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"], ["b", "c", "a", "c", "a", "b"]])
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(list(range(6)), index=idx)
     0
a b  0
  c  1
b a  2
  c  3
c a  4
  b  5
```

I would like to slice out first occurrences of unique combinations of the 2 index levels to get something like this:

```
     0
a b  0
  c  1
b c  3
```

Using `pandas` 0.23.4 and Python 3.6.5 in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) with index values converted to frozensets and then filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[~df.index.map(frozenset).duplicated()]
print (df)
     0
a b  0
  c  1
b c  3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can work on the index values, and similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58592606/find-symmetric-pairs-quickly-in-numpy/58592764#58592764)

```
a = np.sort(df.index.to_list(), axis=1)
df.groupby([a[:,0], a[:,1]], sort=False).first()
```

Or similarly:

```
mask = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.index.to_list(), axis=1)).duplicated()
df[~mask.values]
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an alternative solution by unstacking the frame and using `numpy` boolean indexing.

```
df_u = df.unstack()
df_u[~np.triu(np.ones(3), 1).astype(bool)] = np.nan
df_u = df_u.stack().dropna()
df_u
       0
a b  0.0
  c  1.0
b c  3.0
```

I will check all of the options to see which one performs faster to select the answer. Thank you everyone who posted!